# Firefox, Selenium IDE - wait for popup to load before automatically closing

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a popup that loads after being submitted then auto-closes, and then the parent window loads. My issue is having making sure Selenium waits until the popup has finished loading, closed and the parent window has finished loading.

On slow speed the following code works to make sure we wait until the popup loads:

```
<!--OK button.-->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=_action</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForFrameToLoad</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--Pop up closes. Back to parent window.-->
```

On fast speed, the following code works because it goes to the next command so need to tell it to wait for the popup to finish loading:

```
<!--OK button.-->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=_action</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
    <td>id=head_check</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForFrameToLoad</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--Pop up closes. Back to parent window.-->
```

My issue is I cannot control if the user will run the script in slow or fast speed, and the slow speed results in an error if I try to waitForElementNotPresent:

```
[error] modifyWindow: Window was closed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since slow speed works, we can "slow down" fast speed at the only step it breaks by adding a pause:

```
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```